# 6 month old hitting her head on the floor when turning over onto her back

Tags: play, moving

She just learned how to turn from on-the-stomach to on-the back, but since she's still new at it, she would hit her head onto the floor on her way down (with a soft playmat on top, but still not that soft considering the floor beneath is wood).

Should I be concerned and stop her from doing so on her own? Can she suffer a concussion from hitting her head?

Comment: I think it is probably fine with a playmat and a wood floor. If you are concerned, why not add an extra blanket for padding?

Comment: How does she respond? Does she cry when it happens or is it a little enough bump that it doesn't bother her?

Comment: No , no crying.

Comment: You need the @ symbol to let a user know in comments that you are talking to them. @Catija is how it looks. That just called her and now she will see your message. It does take some time to get used to this site, but we will try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if your child is not crying from it or expressing any kind of pain/discomfort, then she will likely be okay. We had a foam playmat over hard wood floors and even when ours would turn over on hard wood floors he would sometimes bump around. It can be very concerning! But if they are not upset by the slight bump then it is not likely something to worry about.

If it continues and you are concerned always speak to your pediatrician.